# Does Bourbaki's (and Grothendieck's) approach to mathematics survive today?

Tags: soft-question

I am curious if the "[Bourbaki's approach](http://neumann.math.tufts.edu/~mduchin/UCD/111/readings/architecture.pdf)" to mathematics is still a viable point of view in modern mathematics, despite the fact that Bourbaki is vilified by many.

Even more specifically, does anyone actively approach mathematics from the more "yielding" [point of view](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/chap1.pdf) famously practiced by Grothendieck? Which, or what type of, research areas are welcoming to (or practicing) Grothendieck's approach to mathematics?

**Motivation:**

To me, there is a deep question regarding motivation of mathematicians over time which is addressed by this viewpoint. An emphasis on resolving hard technical problems is quite depressing, generally, whereas the idea of finding a general framework which presents a natural and explanatory solution through the development of a vast theory seems very motivating. In such a view, the open problem only serves to motivate a better development of the general theory surrounding the core difficulty, bringing into focus a clearer picture of the essential issue at hand.

It seems to me that carefully developing a general (sometimes axiomatic) theory is analogous to performing scientific experiment. One is not looking to be clever, but instead is filling in data which may, when examined later, reveal clear and natural answers to mathematical questions. Obviously such an approach can be exhausting, in that one must spend much more time to fill in an entire picture than to, at some point, jump to a resolution of a particular question. On the other hand, It may be possible to persevere longer at such a task, as one is not so sensitive to one's loss of quickness or cleverness and can simply engage the task at hand.

Is this viewpoint valid?

---

[**Edited (Dec. 17, 2012) by A. Caicedo**, following suggestions [here](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1490/bourbaki-thread/). Question originally asked by user
[curious1](https://mathoverflow.net/users/29891/curious1).]

Comment: There is room  and need  for both in mathematics but, as  Bertrand Russell used to say, "*the axiomatic method has its advantages, like stealing over honest work*". 

Comment: The formulation of this question is really bad. Is theory-building considered quackery? Is this a joke? Also, the picture of the theory-builder being tempted to take shortcuts and solve a problem is  bizarre. I voted to close as "subjective and argumentative".

Comment: In my opnion Bourbaki's approach is (in some sense) that predominant (in consderable parts of math) that it is not even noticed anymore as some particular approach. It is simply the way things are done. [To appreciate this one would just need to compare pre-Bourbaki texts, Bourbaki, and any number of current moderately adavanced textbooks.]
Voting to close as not a real question. 

Comment: It's a real question, but the answer is clearly "yes". The interesting question is actually the complementary one: what else "survived" the post-1945 rethinking of graduate education in mathematics?

Comment: @Adeel Ahmad Khan: there is some truth to your statement. Indeed, I very briefly had a second version of my comment around that contained something like "I should stress that the Bourbaki approach as I understand it a priori has nothing to do with Grothendieck style of research" I deleted it as CM's comment appeared in between and since his referred to mine I could not delete the old version and thus removed the new. That this is conflated in the question is an additional problem. Bourbaki was (is) first and foremost a group of people that wrote (write) textbooks or perhaps...  

Comment: ...reference works is the better name. As mentioned in the text linked to in the question J.-P. Serre's style of doing research differs signif. from Grothendieck's same for Weil and any number of people that followed and/or (co-)formed the Bournbaki approach. Now, the question whether other people work in the style of Grothendieck is a most vague and subjective question. In addition that sombody might not does not mean they dismiss the idea but perhaps they really would like to but cannot. In any case this then becomes a question: who is the new Grothendieck?, which is clear not suitable.   

Comment: I think this question is worded terribly, but that it contains something of interest. I'd suggest removing the Bourbaki bit altogether and asking about a specific aspect of Grothendieck's approach. BTW: Something characteristic of G's approach would be that he'd probably not even ask this question (he probably wouldn't care what anyone else thought of what he did). Recent developments aside! 

Comment: @John Banon: "he probably wouldn't care what anyone else thought of what he did" I do not know what is recent for you but he wrote and distributed hundreds and hundreds of pages (eg, Récoltes et semailles) explaining what he did, what others did or did not, and what not. How is this compatible?     

Comment: Each person should follow what appeals.  One way of progress is to find new structure which will express intuitive ideas. Another is to find new ways of using existing structures. One way to tackle known problems. Another is to find new questions. S Ulam suggested to me in 1964 at a conference in Sicily that each person should be encouraged to develop the mathematics most appropriate to them. "There are many ways of skinning a cat!" 

Comment: 

@quid: You are probably right. I was basing that comment on Grothendieck's writing about his ability to be alone in what he did.

Comment: Meta thread - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1490/bourbaki-thread/

Comment: I personally feel this topic, while fascinating, is a little too discussion-y (even if we overlook "or is this now regarded as quackery?" which I find very odd) to be a good fit for MO. In any case, I think the answer is a resounding "yes!" - there will always be great mathematicians who manifest the "rising sea" qualities of Grothendieck. Modern examples might include Shelah. I am told that there was a lot of that in Grassmann as well. But I doubt that any of them would think of themselves as primarily "axiomatizers"; it's more a matter of pursuing their inner vision until the mist clears. 

Comment: I find the question interesting and would like to read knowledgeable answers, particularly one that contrasts the OP's use of "structuralism" with how that term is ordinarily understood in the philosophy of mathematics (in particular, as a viewpoint that is surely dominant in mathematics today). But it seems that the OP may have a different sense of this term, and I would like to understand the difference. I have voted to re-open. 

Comment: I find this question "question-begging" in the old sense

Comment: Someone posted a comment once about a bad Erdos still being a decent mathematician, but a bad Grothendieck being terrible. This seems appropriate here...

Comment: I thought of the same thing, Jon. Grothendieck's is a very hard act to pull off. @curious1: what makes you feel that this style of research would be a function of the research area rather than of individual personality? I don't think this is a style you can just *decide* to emulate, and reduce to the spirit of axiomatizing (cf. Liviu's comment). You have to take into account that Grothendieck did mathematics about 16 hours a day, in a more or less constant state of obstinate and fanatical (and delicate and subtle) meditation on mathematical objects. It can be done, but... 

Comment: I was more interested in structuralism than in Grothendieck...

Comment: Please post discussion in the meta thread linked to by Francois, above.  This kind of meta discussion should *not* be here. 

Comment: Dear curious, Grothendieck was a *very* powerful mathematician.  I think it is more useful to think of his style as a manifestation of his power, rather than the converse.  Among other qualities, his power included enormous, penetrating, mathematical insight.  When you write that you "would like to begin to try to do mathematics in this way", this is tantamount to asking "how can I too become a more penetrating mathematician"?  This is a hard question to answer, either in the abstract or in the particular, but I think that using *this* as a criterion for a field is likely to be a mistake. ...

Comment: ... rather, I think it makes more sense to choose a field based on where your strengths, intuitions, and interests lie, and then work hard to develop your understanding of that field.  Regards, 

Comment: It's also worth noting that even Grothendieck did not initially follow Grothendieck's approach to mathematics, e.g. in his work on Grothendieck's inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_inequality

Comment: @Terry Tao, is this really true?  In his paper "Résumé de la théorie métrique des produits tensoriels topologique", one finds the statement in much more generality than stated on Wikipedia (§4, N° 2, th. 1), and the proof seems pretty easy after a typical Grothendieck-style build up of about 50 pages.

Answer (score 14):

Jacob Lurie seems the most obvious answer.  His publication history (deep books published in his own time rather than a bunch of small articles) is indeed of the sort that you allude to at the end, but fortunately he had no trouble being offered a suitable position (while still quite young).

Answer (score 13):

The following appears in "[Reminiscences of Grothendieck and his school](http://www.ams.org/notices/201009/rtx100901106p.pdf)", published in Notices of the AMS:

> Bloch: I wonder whether today such a style of mathematics could exist.
>
> Illusie: Voevodsky’s work is fairly general. Several people tried to imitate Grothendieck, but I’m afraid that what they did never reached that “oily” character dear to Grothendieck.

I am not completely sure what Illusie meant by "oily", but this seems to be a hint:

> Illusie: To him no statement was ever the best one. He could always find something better, more general or more flexible. Working on a problem, he said he had to sleep with it for some time. He liked mechanisms that had oil in them. For this you had to do scales, exercises (like a pianist), consider special cases, functoriality. At the end you obtained a formalism amenable to dévissage.

Comment: I am thinking 'oily' might mean 'slippery', in the sense of being very slow to commit oneself to fixed and precise notions, but to be flexible for as long as possible until, at length, the notions crystallize into a form of satisfying and useful generality and power. I think this is an extremely difficult state for most mathematicians to maintain for any appreciable length of time; it requires an incredible tenacity of inner vision. Working with such a mathematician (I have someone in mind) is both fascinating and frustrating, and 'slippery' is a good word: the ground never feels quite secure!

Comment: @Adeel: thank you for the reference of this wonderful paper of the notices, that I had completely missed.

@Todd. I don't think that "oily" means exactly "slippery" in Illusie's talk.
I'd like to know if Illusie was speaking in French or in English
originally, but I am pretty sure that was he had in mind is the french phrase "bien huilé". One image that can explain this phrase is
that of the engine of a car filled with clean new oil so that it runs smoothly, without jolt. An other translation...

Comment: ... could be "well lubricated". 

Comment: Illusie was speaking in English because the conversation took place in a Chicago apartment in the presence of people not all of whom knew French.  "Bien huilé" is exactly what came to my mind too, when Illusie refers to the "oily" character of Grothendieck's mathematics.

Comment: The phrase "well-lubricated" has other meanings in British English... ;-)

Comment: @Joel: thanks. I'd been thinking over my comment recently, and also thought I might have been off (and was inclining more towards what you're suggesting now). I'll keep my comment up there anyway, just because I think the phenomenon of the 'slippery' mathematician (who is slow to commit definitely to fixed notions) is an interesting one. @Yemon: those meanings are known to Americans as well. 